# Does a software exist to batch convert image at different rotation angle?

Tags: image

I have searched on the web for software that batch convert image at different rotation angle from a source file, but my searches went unsuccessful. Does what I am looking for exists? What would be awesome is an application that we browse for a source image in PNG and a target directory and when a button is pressed the program create every `"source-" + angle + ".png"` like source-1.png to source-360.png.

Anyone know such a program?

**EDIT**

For more clarity, I want to put oriented marker inside google map in a asp.net web app. Since google map api doesn't allow to set the angle we want to show the image, I will set the src of  tag with the link to the wanted angle. Something similar can be found [there](http://radar.zhaw.ch/AirTraffic.html) with the planes (direct link to plane at [0 degree](http://radar.zhaw.ch/images/airplanes/airplane0.png), [180 degree](http://radar.zhaw.ch/images/airplanes/airplane180.png), [290 degree](http://radar.zhaw.ch/images/airplanes/airplane290.png)).

So I have my basic png file 20px by 20px, but I rather prefer not to create 360 images wich would be a pain because I have 6 type of images for now and counting. So I was looking for a little soft that would help me achieve this.

Comment: Are you trying to write such a program or find an existing one? If the former, what language?  If the latter, this should be moved to SuperUser.

Comment: your expected results are clear; you want 360 2d images. But what is your "source"? a 3d model? a panoramic image?

Comment: I specified that I searche don the web and found unrelated thing to what I want to achieve like panoranam 3dm etc and you talk to me about those suject. Seriously I just don't get it. I have a 2D image which I want to rotate and have different files for each of the 360 degree rotation.

Comment: Do you want to write a program or use an existing program?

Comment: My company's Eyebatch software can do it. http://www.atalasoft.com/eyebatch/ It's not free, but we donate all proceeds to charity. If you want to use .NET to do it, we make DotImage Photo, which also makes this pretty easy http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/photo

Comment: you are probably looking at 3D reconstruction of the object from multiple 2D images. something which might be of interest to you http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEOmzjImsVc

Comment: Are you using windows, mac or linux?

Comment: ...no one has mentioned ImageMagick?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: the parent didn't correctly expose the problem. It sounded like 3D stuff at the beginning.

For rotating images, you can use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/)

It is a console program, but it can be used very easily to rotate images. This:

```
convert image.png -rotate 45 image-45.png
```

Will create a new image called image-45.png that is the result of rotating image.png 45 degrees.

You can make a bat or sh file to automatize this process (so you have a proper name and the 360 images generated on a loop). However the script is completely different depending on what platform you are on.

Please include what is your platform (Windows, Linux, Mac) so I can be more specific.

Comment: coming from an image processing background, this is quite a complicated task, IMHO.Using google sketchup, on the other hand, has made it quite easy, if you understand the principles behind it

Comment: mm I removed the sketchup reference days ago. You must have read a cached page.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you could create a short routine in Photoshop that would do this.  Photoshop allows you easily rotate by an arbitrary angle.  You can save this as an action, and then (assuming photoshop hasn't changed too drastically in the last few releases) save that action as an executable that you can run on your images.

Something to consider is that rotating an image, saving it, rotating that modified image, and so on, you will probably encounter increasing picture degradation.  Ideally, you should have all of your rotations based off your original image.  That might make the photoshop solution a bit more difficult...not sure if there's an easy way to put parameters (angle, in your case) into the saved routines.

Finally, are you sure you need 360 images?  I'd suspect that you could get away with maybe 36 images, and just give the user the closest one, and at that image size (you say your input image is 20x20), it would be just fine.

Comment: I don't have photoshop :-( Can't afford it. But you are probably right for the 36 images instead of 360. Kudos for the fact that you posted an answer about my question.

Answer (score 0):

Paste the following code into [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net):

```
using(var sourceImage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Path\To\Image")) {
    for(int angle = 0; angle < 360; angle += 10) {
        using(var newImage = new Bitmap(sourceImage.Width, sourceImage.Height)) 
        using(var g = Graphics.FromImage(newImage)) { 
            g.TranslateTransform(sourceImage.Width / 2, sourceImage.Height / 2);
            g.RotateTransform(angle);
            g.DrawImage(sourceImage, -sourceImage.Width / 2, -sourceImage.Height / 2);

            newImage.Save(@"C:\Whatever\Rotated Images\" + angle + ".png");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are doing is called "affine" transform.  What he is asking for is 360 degree image reconstruction

Comment: yup: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation. Generating 3D object from single/multiple images  is quite comples, considering the perspective nature of the camera (and hence it is called perspective transformation). Generating 3D information from single image is even more harder than with multiple images. look in google for single view meterology

Comment: @Ram: AFAIK, he doesn't have a 3D image.

Comment: yup, you dont need a 3D image to create a  3D representation of the object. see Criminisi's work http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=67278

Comment: The OP does not want a 3d image.  He's looking for rotations of a 2d image.  That's it.